# Explanation of details in SOURCE column of findmnt

Tags: mount, namespace

I have some questions regarding the output of the "findmnt" command, specifically the SOURCE column:

```
TARGET                                        SOURCE                            FSTYPE      OPTIONS
/                                             /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4        rw,relatime,stripe=128
├─/sys                                        sysfs                             sysfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/security                      securityfs                        securityfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup                            cgroup2                           cgroup2     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot
│ ├─/sys/fs/pstore                            pstore                            pstore      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/bpf                               bpf                               bpf         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700
│ ├─/sys/kernel/debug                         debugfs                           debugfs     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ │ └─/sys/kernel/debug/tracing               tracefs                           tracefs     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/tracing                       tracefs                           tracefs     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/fuse/connections                  fusectl                           fusectl     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ └─/sys/kernel/config                        configfs                          configfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
├─/proc                                       proc                              proc        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc                  systemd-1                         autofs      rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=14249
│ │ └─/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc                binfmt_misc                       binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ └─/proc/fs/nfsd                             nfsd                              nfsd        rw,relatime
├─/dev                                        udev                              devtmpfs    rw,nosuid,relatime,size=12251064k,nr_inodes=3062766,mode=755,inode64
│ ├─/dev/pts                                  devpts                            devpts      rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
│ ├─/dev/shm                                  tmpfs                             tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64
│ ├─/dev/mqueue                               mqueue                            mqueue      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ └─/dev/hugepages                            hugetlbfs                         hugetlbfs   rw,relatime,pagesize=2M
├─/run                                        tmpfs                             tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2461576k,mode=755,inode64
│ ├─/run/lock                                 tmpfs                             tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64
│ ├─/run/user/1001                            tmpfs                             tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=2461572k,nr_inodes=615393,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=1001,inode64
│ ├─/run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service none                              ramfs       ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700
│ ├─/run/rpc_pipefs                           sunrpc                            rpc_pipefs  rw,relatime
│ └─/run/snapd/ns                             tmpfs[/snapd/ns]                  tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2461576k,mode=755,inode64
│   ├─/run/snapd/ns/docker.mnt                nsfs[mnt:[4026533301]]            nsfs        rw
│   └─/run/snapd/ns/lxd.mnt                   nsfs[mnt:[4026533302]]            nsfs        rw
├─/home/user/container_practice/fakeroot      tmpfs                             tmpfs       rw,relatime,inode64
├─/snap/core18/2566                           /dev/loop1                        squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/core20/1623                           /dev/loop3                        squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/docker/1779                           /dev/loop4                        squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/docker/2285                           /dev/loop5                        squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/lxd/22923                             /dev/loop6                        squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/snapd/17336                           /dev/loop9                        squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/snapd/17029                           /dev/loop8                        squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/lxd/23541                             /dev/loop7                        squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/boot                                       /dev/sda2                         ext4        rw,relatime,stripe=128
```

1. Some mounts have devices as their SOURCE, which makes sense to me, but why is the SOURCE a file system type in a bunch of them?
2. For the mount at /run/snapd/ns, what does "tmpfs[/snapd/ns]" in the SOURCE column mean? "/snapd/ns" does not exist on the filesystem.
3. How can I create a mount (from the command line) that would produce similar output in the SOURCE column for /run/snapd/ns?
4. Similar to question 2, for the 2 mounts under /run/snapd/ns, what does "tmpfs[mnt:[4026533302]]" in the SOURCE column mean?
5. What does a value of "none" mean?

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  We can discuss other issues after that is resolved. Any particular OS or is this general to all Linux distributions and all UNIX variants?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. findmnt is found on most anything mainstream running linux, and there are questions about findmnt on here currently, so I figured this is the place to ask a question about findmnt; and I hope for an answer that talks about the underpinnings implemented by the kernel, such as namespaces, that support the mount profile specifics I'm asking about.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.